# Is there a term for this?

Tags: phrase-usage

I just read an opinion that criticized another writer for 'encompassing generalizations' that actually was an encompassing generalization, itself.  Is there a term for this?  He maintains it is a double entendre, but I don't think so.

Comment: It's a bit trichotomous, but (a) it *is* technically a «double entendre» (word play on *generalisations that encompass* versus *generalisations that are encompassed*); and (b) the term you’re looking for, and he’s trying to avoid, is *double standard*, which I’m sure you could have found by looking in a dictionary under *double* :0/

Comment: You might have a question here if you worked on the question a bit.  Are you trying to ask for a word about "encompassing generalizations" or are your looking for a word where you make a point by mimicking a mistake another makes ?

Comment: "mocking" is the word you are looking for if the second http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mocking?s=t   it's second definition "2.
to ridicule by mimicry of action or speech; mimic derisively."

Comment: It sounds vaguely self-reflexive.

Comment: The pot calling the kettle black (you do tag 'phrase usage'). Hypocrisy.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  Will, I believe that double standard is the key here.  Not sure if I'd found it today, but thanks.  Tom, it was the manner in which he decided to criticize... doubt very much that he was 'mimicking'.  Hot Licks and Edwin, those seem to be what this person was doing, albeit not intentionally.  He said, "your wrong", and said it twice.  Sorry, but that hits one of my many grammar sore spots and I just needed the verbiage I could not get a handle on.  I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: ah nevermind lol .. the second guy was the one even more wrong.. he wasn't trying to mock the first facetiously.. he fell in the same trap

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, self-referential functions are described as being defined recursively. Note of caution: the phenomenon described is also capable of creating logical black holes: e.g. "Sweeping generalizations are always wrong," or "This statement is false."